# Prove that $(\frac{bc+ac+ab}{a+b+c})^{a+b+c} \geq \sqrt{(bc)^a(ac)^b(ab)^c}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

> Prove that $$\left( \frac{bc+ac+ab}{a+b+c} \right)^{a+b+c} \ge \sqrt{(bc)^a(ac)^b(ab)^c}$$
>   where $a,b,c>0$

**My attempt:**

[image]

I couldn't proceed after that.  Please help me in this regard, thanks!

Comment: where do you people come up with these

Comment: @djechlin what do you mean

Comment: djechlin probably means: Could you add the origin of the problem? In general, (it is advised to [provide some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for the question. If you look at [recently closed questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a1), missing context is probably the most frequent reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove that 
$$(a+b+c)\ln\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a+b+c}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}a\ln{bc}$$ or
$$\ln\left(\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a+b+c}\right)^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}\ln{bc}.$$
But by Jensen $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}\ln{bc}\leq\ln\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{abc}{a+b+c}$$
Thus, it remains to prove that $$\frac{3abc}{a+b+c}\leq\left(\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a+b+c}\right)^2,$$
which is 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: Nice +1.  Perhaps could be made simpler just assuming $a+b+c=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you suggest the fault in my attempt.I made the first inequality by writing a b-times,b c-times,c a-times and applying AM-GM inequality.similarly by writing bc a-times,ca b-times,ab c-times I wrote the second inequality but the conclusion in my attempt is faulty as in  @AshwaniSharmaAdv answer.

Comment: @navinstudent It says only that your way is wrong, which does not say that does not exist another way, for which we can prove your inequality. I am sorry if I understand your question not right.

Answer (score 1):

$a^bb^cc^a\ge\sqrt{(ab)^c(bc)^a(ca)^b}$

$\implies a^{2b}b^{2c}c^{2a}\ge a^{b+c}b^{c+a}c^{a+b}$

$\implies a^bb^cc^a\ge a^cb^ac^b$

It doesn't seems true always because of simmatry..

Comment: then maybe i have committed mistake somewhere.but couldnot get it.i wrote a times,b c times and c a times and applied am-gm inequality.similar by writing bc a times,..,,i wrote the second inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the weighted AM-GM inequality, considering

\begin{align*}
  \frac{bc+ca+ab}{a+b+c} &=
  \frac{2(bc+ca+ab)}{2(a+b+c)} \\
  &= \frac{(b+c)\color{red}{\boldsymbol{a}}+
           (c+a)\color{green}{\boldsymbol{b}}+
           (a+b)\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{c}}}{(b+c)+(c+a)+(a+b)} \\
  \left( \frac{bc+ca+ab}{a+b+c} \right)^{2(a+b+c)}
  &\ge
  \color{red}{\boldsymbol{a}}^{b+c}
  \color{green}{\boldsymbol{b}}^{c+a}
  \color{blue}{\boldsymbol{c}}^{a+b} \\
  \left( \frac{bc+ca+ab}{a+b+c} \right)^{a+b+c}
  &\ge \sqrt{a^{b+c}b^{c+a}c^{a+b}} \\
  &= \sqrt{(bc)^{a}(ca)^{b}(ab)^{c}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is easy and simple.